# Passing a list to plotly mode

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, visualization

I have a dataset that contains theoretical and experimental data that I would like to plot onto the same graph. I would like it so that the theoretical data is plotted with "lines" and the experimental data is plotted with "markers". What makes this a bit challenging is that the two datasets have a different number of datapoints.

I've created a simplified reproducible example:

```
library(plotly)
library(colorBlindness)

experimentaldata<-data.frame(hours=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                             concentration=c(0.25, 0.3, 0.8, 0.75, 0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 0.98, 1),
                             name=c("Chloride", "Chloride", "Chloride", "Sulfate", "Sulfate", "Sulfate", "Bicarbonate", "Bicarbonate", "Bicarbonate"))

theoreticaldata<-data.frame(hours=c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9),
                            concentration=c(0.45, 0.38, 0.27, 0.8, 0.66),
                            name=c("Chloride_exp", "Chloride_exp", "Chloride_exp", "Sulfate_exp", "Sulfate_exp")
                            )

allchemicals<-rbind(experimentaldata, theoreticaldata)


fig<-plot_ly(allchemicals, x=~hours, y=~concentration,type='scatter', mode="lines", color=~name, colors=SteppedSequential5Steps)
  
print(fig)
```

This code takes two datasets, binds them together, then plots them. I've tried to pass the modes as a list, like

modes=c("markers", "markers", "markers",...,"lines") but it can only take one mode at a time. Is there any solution to this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this with `add_trace()`?

```
fig <- plot_ly(experimentaldata, x=~hours, y=~concentration,type='scatter', 
                mode="lines", 
                color=~name, colors=SteppedSequential5Steps)

fig %>% add_trace(data=theoreticaldata, y=~concentration,
              x=~hours,
              mode='markers')
```

[image]